# SQL Query does not work in ModelBuilder (but works elsewhere)?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, sql, error-000230

I am having issues getting a simple SQL query to work in ModelBuilder. It works fine when I use it with the standard "Select features by attributes tool", but ModelBuilder doesn't find the required fields.

```
"Sheet1$.Number" is not NULL AND Pipe.CLASS = 'IS17' AND "Sheet1$.CLASS" not like '17'
```

> ERROR 000230: Failed selecting with "Sheet1$.Number" is not NULL AND Pipe.CLASS = 'IS17' AND "Sheet1$.CLASS" not like '17'
>   An expected Field was not found or could not be retrieved properly.
>   An expected Field was not found or could not be retrieved properly. [Pipe]
>   Failed to execute (Make Feature Layer).

Comment: is Pipe a feature in a file gdb? if not, it might require delimiters as well, described [here](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00s500000033000000)

Comment: Thanks @fluidmotion, it is an FGDB - I *think* the issue may be the fields from the joined table. If I strip the query down to basics, it will return anything native to the fgdb however when attempting to extract anything from the joined fields; it fails.

Comment: is the join defined in modelbuilder? or is modelbuilder working on a layer within the project rather than the feature in the fgdb?

Comment: To try and progress this would you be able to show us what some simple test data and a simple model would look like that would enable us to reproduce what you are describing, please?  Also, what version of ArcGIS are you using?